# Convert XML feed as RSS

Tags: xml, rss, asp.net-web-api2, iis-7.5

I already have an existing setup of outputting RSS feed item in the expected format (example below). The only problem is that the solution is based off of .XML url format and not .rss

Is there an easy way to convert the url to feedname.rss instead of feedname.xml?

The application is built using WEB API 2 and hosted on IIS 7.

Essentially what I want is the url to remain .rss and the request to go in my application. I tried adding "Mime Types" to enable .rss (text/xml) and it did not work.

Example of current XML feed

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Testfeed</title>
<link>
http://someurl.com
</link>
<description>Test feed</description>
<language>en-US</language>
<copyright>Copyright (c) 2017</copyright>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 04 May 2017 12:20:48 -0400</lastBuildDate>
<item>
<guid isPermaLink="true">
http://someurl.com
</guid>
<link>
http://someurl.com
</link>
<category>
<![CDATA[ somecategory ]]>
</category>
<category>
<![CDATA[ somesubcat ]]>
</category>
<author>
<![CDATA[ Michael Smith ]]>
</author>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Error : HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

In the application did the following in Web.config :

```
<handlers>
 <add name="RSS Request Handler" path="*.rss" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />    
</handlers>
```